# Errors while adding splash screen in android

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am new to android development, and I'm trying to add a splash screen in my app.
I found this [tutorial:](http://androidmkab.com/2016/04/09/how-to-add-animated-splash-screen-to-you-android-app-using-android-studio/)

I have added the files as mentioned in the tutorial but it doesn't seems to work, there is an error in my `Splashscreen.java` file

It gives me the error *cannot resolve symbol androidmkab*

Thanks for helping in advance.

**Splashscreen.java**

```
package com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity;

import java.util.Random;


public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

    Thread splashTread;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        int[] ids = new int[]{R.drawable.s_img,R.drawable.s_image_black, R.drawable.s_image_black2};
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int r= randomGenerator.nextInt(ids.length);
        this.imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(ids[r]));

        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    // Splash screen pause time
                    while (waited < 3500) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                }

            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

}
```

**activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

`import com.androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity;` remove this line from the `top`. Its not your package... instead make it `import com.myapplication.MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be that you are trying to call a package which does not exist in your project. `androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity` should be replaced with your project package. such as `com.myApplication.MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line `com.androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity;` and write `com.myapplication.MainActivity;`